# Availability of Push notification service in this situation?

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications

i'm working on a football application. the application connects to a webservice and gets the required data via soap request whenever a tab is opened. one of the tab shows live matches of the current day. when the live tab is opened, it refreshes the view by a timer and shows the status updates (goal scored, half time or full time). what i need to do is getting the status updates when the app is closed. the user will select max 2 competitions from settings of the app. then the status updates about these 2 competitions needed to be alerted.  can i use push notification service to send soap requests and make alerts according to the response? or does it only allow getting response? or is there anyway that i can do it?

thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear what you are asking. The part where you write:

```
can i use push notification service to send soap
requests and make alerts according to the response?
or does it only allow getting response?
```

isn't really clear to me. What response are you talking about?

In any case.. push notification is what is says. It pushes a notification to the iPhone.

It does not:

- activate your application in the background
- allow for any action of your application without the user opening said application first
- allow any kind of data to be gather from the phone

If you want the user's phone to talk to your server, the user will need to open your application. If that's what you're asking.

Comment: i want my application to send requests and get responses about matches  after the user closes the application. i meant to ask if it s possible to do it with push notification service?

Comment: You can have your server send a push notification to the user. When the user gets the push, he can choose to open the application. Then, your application can do whatever you program it to do (send and receive). But before the user opens the application, the application cannot send anything. Push service will only allow you to push a message to the phone, like SMS basically.

Comment: "the application cannot send anything. Push service will only allow you to push a message to the phone" that s my answer, thank u